# Watson Conversation: Show user all entities

Tags: ibm-watson, spring-el, watson-conversation

In Watson conversation. I have an entity Fruit

```
Fruit values:
    -Apple     
    -Orange
    -Banana
    -Kiwi
```

I'd like to create a new dialog where the intent of the user is to get a list of all the values of a specific entity, in this case a list of all the fruits, . So the conversation should go:

```
User: "What fruits do you have?"
```

And then I'd like Watson to respond

```
Watson: "The fruits we got in store are: Apple, Orange, Banana, Kiwi"
```

All the stuff I found is of **recognizing** an entity in users input, such as

```
User: "Do you have apples?"
```

And Watson picking up **Apples**

**Just to clarify**, setting an array with the possible options declarativly on a context variable as shown below is no good for me, I need to get them dynamically from the entity

```
{
  "context": {
    "fruits": [
      "lemon",
      "orange",
      "apple"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "This is the array: <? $fruits.join(', ') ?>"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

Thankss!

Comment: Do you mean you want to access how the entity is defined? Each entity value can have synonyms. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Some examples of how to access "stuff" that I have been collecting: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables

Comment: @data_henrik please correct me if I'm wrong, to my understanding, synonyms should be used to interpret an entity from an input of the user (ex: John could be a synonym of an entity with the value Jonathan, so if the user inputs "I'd like to take a turn with John", Watson knows he is talking about the entity who's value is Jonathan). My need is to specifically list the user the **values** of each instance of an entity. In this case in the entity Fruits, there is an instance for each value [ "Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Kiwi"]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible to directly access the workspace metadata from within a dialog. You have access to what was detected using the intents, entities and context variables. However, I see two options you have:

1. Use your application program that drives the chat to access the entity definitions on the fly, then create a context variable in which you offer the entity choices. The [API to list entities](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#get_entities) can be used from any programming language and there are SDKs.
2. With a relatively new feature you can [invoke server or client actions from within a dialog node](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions), i.e., make programmatic calls. Use that and the API mentioned above to obtain the list of entity values.

.